# get a specific substring after and before a character in a string python

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split  time from decription strings. 
`desc` can have this kind of strings:

```
desc = '08:59 Hudh aes ....' 
desc = '19:59Aksi jeh....' 
desc = 'just letters without time'
desc = '21.19:55Aksi hsue....'
desc = '256.08:59Aksi mane....'
```

`time` contains 10 first letters of description 
I want to  find `:` and then to take two numbers before it and after it, so i can split the time

```
time = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x, desc[0:10].replace(" " , "")))
print  "Time:" , time , time.rsplit(':', 1)[0]
```

`time.rsplit(':', 1)[0]` returns all numbers before `:`

`time.rsplit(':', 1)[0]` returns all numbers after `:`

How to define to split only two numbers after and before `:` ?Is this a good way? Is better idea to use regex, i tried but it's a little complicated?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `re.finditer()`

```
 test = """desc = '08:59 Hudh aes ....' 
 desc = '19:59Aksi jeh....' 
 desc = 'just letters without time'
 desc = '21.19:55Aksi hsue....'
 desc = '256.08:59Aksi mane....'
 """
 pattern = r"\d{2}:\d{2}"
 for m in re.finditer(pattern,test):
    print m.group()
```

Output will be:

> 08:59
>   19:59
>   19:55
>   08:59

Then from this output you can split the hours and minutes easily

Answer (score 1):

> How to define to split only two numbers after and before :

With regex; the following regex pattern matches *exactly* 2 digits, followed by a colon, followed by *exactly* two digits (which is literally what you ask for):

```
import re

desc = '21.19:55Aksi hsue....'
m = re.search(r'(\d{2}):(\d{2})', desc)
if m:
    hour, min = m.groups()
else:
    # no time in desc string
    pass
print 'hour = {}, min = {}'.format(hour, min)
```

**Output**

```
hour = 19, min = 55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `re.findall()`:

```
re.findall(r'([\d.]+):([\d.]+)',desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are separated each other you can use a `re.search` method like this:

```
import re
[hour, min, desc] = re.search(r'(?:(?:\d+\.)?(\d{2}):(\d{2}))?[ \t]*(.*)',desc).groups()

# --
# desc  = '08:59 Hudh aes ....'
# hour -> '08'
# min  -> '59'
# desc -> 'Hudh aes ....', the space before the description are stripped too
# --
# desc  = '19:59Aksi jeh....'
# hour -> '19'
# min  -> '59'
# desc -> 'Aksi jeh....'
# --
# desc  = 'just letters without time'
# hour -> None
# min  -> None
# desc -> 'just letters without time'
# --
# desc = '256.08:59Aksi mane....'
# hour -> '08'
# min  -> '59'
# desc -> 'Aksi mane....'
```

[Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cS2sT6/3)